Matchthem and Marginaleffect
This is my code:
# Perform matching in each imputed dataset
m.out_model1 <- matchthem(Treatment_type_tumor_near_gallbladder ~ age + sex + bmi + ASA + comorbidities + Systemic_treatment_prior_local_treatment + Segments_treated_per_session + Metastasis_size_at_treatment_mm + min_distance_gallblad_mm + stage_binary, 
data = new_amcore_imputed, 
method = "nearest", 
distance = "logit",
replace = TRUE,
ratio = 3,
caliper = 0.2)

# Perform a logistic regression on the matched data
results <- with(m.out_model1, svyglm(complications ~ Treatment_type_tumor_near_gallbladder + age + sex + bmi + ASA + comorbidities + Systemic_treatment_prior_local_treatment + Segments_treated_per_session + Metastasis_size_at_treatment_mm + min_distance_gallblad_mm + stage_binary,
family = quasibinomial()), cluster = FALSE)

How can I correctly use the marginaleffects::avg_comparisons() function after this step?
I tried the following:
# Compute average marginal effects
comparisons <- marginaleffects::avg_comparisons(results)
summary(comparisons, exponentiate = TRUE)

However, I am not sure if this is correct, as the output was not what I expected. I followed the tutorial provided here: https://ngreifer.github.io/blog/treatment-effects-mi/, but I am unable to apply it to my case.
I also tried this approach, that gives me a more understandable output:
output <- pool(results, dfcom = NULL)

summary(output, exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE) %>%     
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, digits = 3))

Are these two approaches comparable?
Thank you in advance for your help!

The approach that doesn't use avg_comparisons() computes an estimate of the conditional odds ratio. That is the the quantity matching is designed to estimate. If that is your quantity of interest, there is no benefit to using matching; you are throwing away data without relaxing the very strong assumption that your outcome model is correctly specified and the conditional odds ratio is constant across all units. So I do not recommend that approach. In fact, I specifically recommend against it in the MatchIt vignette on estimating effects.
You'll notice in the blog, I don't use MatchThem. Here is some code to run this analysis using MatchThem:
comp.imp <- lapply(results$analyses, function(fit) {
  avg_comparisons(fit, newdata = subset(treat == 1),
                  variables = "treat",
                  comparison = "lnratioavg")
})

comp.imp |> pool() |> summary(exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE)

(Note: you can ignore the warning about not including the wts argument.) This returns the ATT on the risk ratio scale. To get the ATT on the odds ratio scale, change comparison to "lnoravg". To get the ATT on the risk difference scale, remove comparison and exponentiate.
Unlike the approach that omits avg_comparisons(), this method correctly targets the marginal estimand, which doesn't depend on the correctness of the outcome model as long as the matching performed well.

As always, thank you, Noah. I’m fascinated by the complexity of this subject! I especially appreciate the consistent support you provide to the community.

@LudovicoAmbrosi Thanks for the kind words! If my answer helped you, please mark the question as solved so it doesn't stay on the unanswered list.
